# SQL Agent Jobs Failing

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server 2012 Ent running in a 3 node cluster.

My jobs were all running fine under a domain admin account "service account".

I am able to log on the server AND use Windows authentication to connect to the instances using the domain admin account but all of the jobs scheduled under the account have started to fail with

> "The job failed.  Unable to determine if the owner (US\domainaccnt) of job AX12_AOS_Clean has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'US\domainaccnt', error code 0x5. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404))."

I have temporarily switched to running most under SA and that works fine, except for my log shipping jobs that are not able to connect to the network share.

It does not appear to be an issue with the account or AD as I can authenticate the user account to AD outside of SQL Server.

I have read several posts on the same error but none apply to my issue.  Any help or suggestions in trouble shooting would be appreciated.

I've thought of changing the account SQL Agent runs under just to see if that fixes it but would like input first.

Also "Execute AS" fails: "`Msg 15404, Level 16, State 19, Line 1
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user`"

Comment: I don't want to be the guy that says "something changed" but something changed. Windows patch. Group policy. Something in Axapta? Changing the service account user will probably fix the problem, but may cause other side-effects if you don't have the roles and permissions configured. Check the Windows Logs on the SQL Server for any clues?

Comment: Jacob, the service account it what they were all scheduled under originally and I can log into both the server AND the sql instance with that same service account.  SQL Server Agent  is not able to authenticate to AD but the SERVER is able to.  Looking for thoughts on why SQL Server Agent can't authenticate the same user the server can (i.e. I can RDP with the same creds)